# Podman local registry: are images duplicated?

Tags: image, podman

My user has several images locally in the `rootless_storage_path` directory as in `/etc/containers/storage.conf`. If the images are pushed on a local registry, are they duplicated? Or Podman uses the same disk space and knows that the images are both for the users and the registry?

Comment: `/etc/containers` isn't used by docker. That's a competing product.

Comment: Indeed, I'm using Podman... The title is corrected

Comment: The image are duplicated. The running registry doesn't know it's running under Podman, doesn't know about the users storage, and may even use a different storage format (this answer would be identical if you were running Docker instead of Podman).

Comment: Well - if your image storage is on a suitably smart filesystem with de-duplication it might not take up any more storage. But that isn't anything to do with podman itself.